# A long sentence from "The Apple Tree"

Tags: meaning, sentence

> If she had long lost the blue-eyed, flower-like charm, the cool slim purity of face and form, the apple-blossom colouring, which had so swiftly and so oddly affected Ashurst twenty-six years ago, she was still at forty-three a comely and faithful companion, whose cheeks were faintly mottled, and whose grey-blue eyes had acquired a certain fullness.

I really cannot get a shot at what the above sentence means. Can anybody give an explanation?

Comment: The clue is in the fifth word *lost*. The sentence is referring to her fading looks.

Comment: I grab this sentence from a novel "The Apple Tree" authored by John  Galsworthy, British.

Comment: Is this even on topic? I don't know.

Comment: You could replace *If* with *Although* and not change the meaning. Otherwise, you really have to be more specific about what you fail to understand.  This is a long sentence, but it's not particularly complex.

Comment: Off topic: criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means she wasn't as good-looking as she used to be when she was younger, but at forty-three she still had what Ashurst considered a pleasing appearance and he liked having her around.

Answer (score 3):

The main clause is ‘she was still at forty-three a comely and faithful companion’. ‘Companion’ is post-modified by the two relative clauses that begin ‘whose cheeks . . .’ and ‘whose grey-blue eyes .  .’

The first part of the sentence, ‘If she . . . years ago’, qualifies the positive qualities described in the second part.

Comment: I don't get "If she had long lost the blue-eyed". Does it mean she has lost the charm or not?

Comment: And can I say she is forty-three years old now from "she was still at forty-three a comely and faithful companion"?

Comment: See if you find it easier to understand by substituting _while_ for _if_. She has lost her earlier charm, but some attractions remain. Yes, it means she was 43 at the time of the description.

Comment: Or again, use *Even if* for the first *If*. Even if X has happened, Y still holds true.

Comment: Yes, @AndrewLeach. This is a rather literary use of _if_ to mean _even if_.